# How can I use the Google Calendar API with Node.js and send event notifications to attendees? And add this as an event in their calendar

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am creating an event where I am adding attendees. I want to send them the notification of that link and add to their calendar. Is this possible?

I will be able to send notification to the attendee email irrespective of the platform ( email can be of outlook, ical, google calendar .. etc) and they receive reminder on their calendar.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. You need to register to Google Cloud Console, enable Google Calendar API.
You will have no difficulty finding information online.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/tutorials?hl=it

Note that to send notifications to invitees, they must have a Google Calendar account or an email address that supports calendar notifications.